# Powerbuilder PFC : Where to start learning

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

Ok, I am an absolute beginner in powerbuilder. Currently I am working in a company where powerbuilder is being used to develop an application. This application heavily uses PFC.

Now I had no prior powerbuilder training when I joined this company, but I learned a few things while working in this application, e.g., datawindow, powerscript etc. But I still can't get my head around all the PFC things that are being used.

So where can I get a quick start tutorial on PFC? How should I proceed with this?

All types of suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at [my article](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/PFC_Notes/15-Minute_PFC_Learning_Curve/15-minute_pfc_learning_curve.html). The point is to learn the basics, and don't sweat about learning "all the things" up front. Learn the basics (so you don't screw up things you'll regret later :-) ) and learn the rest as you go along, picking off pieces that interest you.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Sybase documentation for the PFC.  This is for PB9 but not much has changed with the PFC since then.

[PFC Object Reference](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pb/pbg0900e/pfcoref/@Generic__BookView)

[PFC User's Guide](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pb/pbg0900e/pfcug/@Generic__BookView)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [article](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/107011) called ["PowerBuilder Foundation Classes"](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/107011). It appears to be based on the PFC chapter of the book ["PowerBuilder 9 Advanced Client/Server Development."](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325004)